# Как получить список доступных шрифтов в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, шрифты

Как получить список доступных в системе шрифтов и, например, закинуть его в ComboBox на форме?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Свойство `Fonts` типа `TStrings` содержит список шрифтов, доступных на данном компьютере. Его можно использовать в приложении, чтобы проверять, имеется ли на компьютере тот или иной шрифт.

Например, можно поместить в приложении компонент `TComboBox` (поле со списком) и в обработчике события `OnCreate` формы поместить туда перечень всех доступных шрифтов:

```
ComboBox1.Items := Screen.Fonts;
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
```

Тогда в нужный момент можно выбрать подходящий шрифт из списка. Для этого в обработчик события `OnClick` или `OnChange` списка можно вставить следующий оператор:

```
Memo1.Font.Name := ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];
```